# delete life when user gives wrong answer

Tags: java, android

I have a question answer game and user have 3 lifes in the Mainactivity when user gives the wrong answer it goes back to mainactivity then I wanna delete 1 life for his wrong answer and that must repeat I'm putting a intent from question activity and delete life according to this but my problem is I don't know how to delete them in order in my code  deletes all 3 life at once how can I make it delete first life3 after if he gives wrong answer delete life2 and after life1 here is my code.

```
public void lifecalculate(){
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    lifecode=intent.getIntExtra("lifecode",4);
    if(life3.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
        if(lifecode==3){
            life3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
    if(life3.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE&&life2.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
        if(lifecode==3){
            life2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
    if(life2.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE&&life1.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
        if(lifecode==3){
            life1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

I know why the code deletes all 3 but don't know how to make it work right.

Comment: You can use startActivityOnResult and in your other activity, when returns, add the data you want to pass in the intent. Then on MainActivity override onActivityResult method. [Here the documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result&ved=2ahUKEwjegPv_-r_yAhUB_7sIHY5hDS0QFnoECDoQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2zwI_xW8Y-TmYmDixc1HKP)

Comment: You can also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68864472/9015853) if you need an example on how to do other than the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to comment. From what I understood, I think that you should give a look at sharedPreferences, and ways to manage data persistence. With SharedPreferences you would be able to use locally stored data instead of passing info in the intents, also if the user closes the app, right now you would lost everything, with SharedPreferences (or a local sqlite database, but I think that it's a bit overkilled for what you're trying to do) you can restore everything. Also the data management would be way easier.